# c++: вывод в консоль текста с несколькими цветами - наиболее производительное решение

Tags: c++, консоль, текст, color

У меня стоит задача вывести в виде текста двумерный массив, где каждому элементу соответствует свой цвет.

Поскольку таких массивов выводится много, то хотелось бы какие-нибудь производительное решение.

Сейчас я делаю это следующим образом:

```
HANDLE console = ::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

for (int y = 0; y < m_fieldHeight; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < m_fieldWidth; x++)
    {
        const int index = x + y * m_fieldWidth;

        const char letter = (char)0xdb;

        ::SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, 15 - m_fieldData[index]);
        std::cout << letter << letter;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

::SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE);
```

получается, что я вывожу 1 символ (двойной, чтобы казаться квадратом), 1 цвет
можно ли это как-то оптимизировать, ускорить

например, как-то подготовить буфер в котором будет уже информация о цвете каждого символа, а затем вывести все за раз (если это конечно будет производительнее)

или такой возможности не предусмотрено?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит использовать [`WriteConsoleOutputAttribute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputattribute). Этот метод позволяет записывать сразу массив атрибутов. И аналогичный метод `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` для вывода сразу массива символов.

Comment: смущает только то, что там активно используется COORD, а хотелось бы когда хочу, выводить следующую строку ниже и начинать COORD оттуда